# Update Status on linkedin

Tags: asp.net

i want to update status on linkedin using linkedin user id, i am developing my final year degree project of social bookmaring site, i dont want to save username and password of the user, i am only saving userid of the user. plz help me.

when user login in to my site , only first time i want to authenticate user and next time in future i use Userid if linkedin to post his status.

Answer (score 0):

### Use ASP.NET Profiles.

### http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2y3fs9xs.aspx